# How do I sort a numerical list with names attached?

Tags: python, sorting

My code is designed to extract data from a text file and add it to a list. I have successfully sorted it alphabetically using .sort(). However, I cannot sort the data numerically as it is a mix of numbers and letters.

```
list2=[]
list2=open('list_data2.txt').readlines()
list2.sort()
print (list2)
```

My text file says:

```
Bob,two,4,5,2
Gerald,five,6,9,3
Abby,one,4,1,9
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I want the first number eg 4 for bob displayed highest to lowest

Comment: did you want to do sorting on third field?

Comment: yes I need the highest from each of the lines displayed in the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the elements separately :

```
l2=[]
with open('list_data2.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
   l=line.strip().split(',')
   l2.append(sorted(l[:2])+sorted(l[2:],reverse=True))

print l2
```

Result:

```
[['Bob', 'two', '5', '4', '2'], 
 ['Gerald', 'five', '9', '6', '3'], 
 ['Abby', 'one', '9', '4', '1']]
```

Also you can join the result :

```
for i in l2:
  print ','.join(i)

Bob,two,5,4,2
Gerald,five,9,6,3
Abby,one,9,4,1
```

Not that in this case we are sorting the digits lexicographicaly that as @Padraic Cunningham says it will fails for digits length more than 1. in that case you need to convert your numbers list elements to `int` then sort :

```
l2=[]
with open('list_data2.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
   l=line.strip().split(',')
   l2.append(sorted(l[:2])+sorted(map(int,l[2:]),reverse=True))

print l2
```

Comment: when I try to add a print to the end of this I get
[['1', 'bob', '5', '4', '2\n']]
[['1', 'bob', '5', '4', '2\n'], ['5', 'thing', '9', '6', '3\n']]
[['1', 'bob', '5', '4', '2\n'], ['5', 'thing', '9', '6', '3\n'], ['2', 'A', '9', '4', '1']]

Comment: @Daynewave you need to print the list out of the `for` loop, check out the edit!

Comment: if your still there where exactly would I add the
for i in l2:
    print (',').join(i)
 
into the code?

Comment: @Daynewave Outside the `with` and `for`!

Comment: This is wrong as you are sorting ints as strings, as soon as you meet double digits you are going to be in trouble

Comment: Sorry for being stupid but when I run the program I get:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, thanks for attention! fixed!

Comment: You also need to strip the newlines

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would like to sort by one of the three last numerical fields.

```
# this sorts by the value of the third field
list2.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(',')[2]))
```

---

Edit: if you want to sort in reverse order, just add `reverse=True`:

```
list2.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(',')[2]), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the original file use the  csv module to get the rows and write to a `NamedTemporaryFile` then use shutil.move to replace the old file with the updated file:

```
import csv
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move

with open('in.txt') as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w",delete=False, dir=".") as out:
    r, wr = csv.reader(f), csv.writer(out)
    for row in r:
        wr.writerow(row[:2] + sorted(row[2:], key=int,reverse=True))
move(out.name,"in.txt")
```

Output:

```
Bob,two,5,4,2
Gerald,five,9,6,3
Abby,one,9,4,1
```

If you don't pass the key as `int` `"11"` will be considered < `"2"`, you need to sort as ints not strings.

Or use `fileinput.input` with `inplace=True`:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("in.txt", inplace=True):
    row = line.strip().split(",")
    print(",".join((row[:2]+sorted(row[2:], key=int, reverse=True)),end=""))
```